# Django model form using forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField

Tags: django, checkbox, django-forms, many-to-many, modelform

I have a ModelForm in my Django app that uses a forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField, which displays as a forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple widget on the form. This ModelForm is used to select/de-select values for a many-to-many relation.  Here's the problem: when you uncheck all of the checkboxes and save the form, it doesn't save.  If you uncheck all but 1, it does save properly.

Are there any tricks I'm missing here about model forms and many-to-many relations?  Am I encountering a bug? I'm new to Django.  Thanks in advance.

Custom Field:

```
class NetworkMessageChoiceField(forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.display_message
```

Model Form:

```
class MessageTemplateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    network_messages = NetworkMessageChoiceField(queryset=NetworkMessageTemplate.objects, 
                                             widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())        
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('network_messages',)
```

View that saves form:

```
def save_message_templates(request, extra_context=dict()):
    try:
        profile_obj = request.user.get_profile()
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        profile_obj = UserProfile(user=request.user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MessageTemplateForm(request.POST, instance=profile_obj)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')

    return index(request, message_template_form=form)
```

**Edit:**

My form field was missing Required=False.

```
class MessageTemplateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    network_messages = NetworkMessageChoiceField(queryset=NetworkMessageTemplate.objects, 
                                                 widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
                                                 required=False)        
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('network_messages',)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't paste what your model looks like, so I am guessing that `network_messages` field in your model is required. If that is the case, then when you attempt to submit the form with the value of that field as `NULL` (empty), then `form.is_valid()` is not returning `True` and therefore your `form.save()` is never being executed.

Have you tried executing this stuff from an interactive shell, instantiating the form and attempting to manually `save()` it?

Comment: Thank you! That was completely the answer.  I just figured it out after posting my question. I was missing Required=False on my form field!

 class MessageTemplateForm(forms.ModelForm):
  network_messages = NetworkMessageChoiceField(queryset=NetworkMessageTemplate.objects, 
              widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
              required=False)        
  class Meta:
   model = UserProfile
   fields = ('network_messages',)

Comment: Excellent! Glad to be of service.